# Creating a UISwitch with custom images on it, and a custom height in width. Trying to use RCSwitch, is there a better way?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswitch

I'm trying to use [RCSwitch](http://osiris.laya.com/projects/rcswitch/) but it's not working unfortunately, as it seems limited to the standard height of 29px. My switch is 35px high (it simply works better for my app). It looks like this:

[image]

My goal is to have that animate to another state, where it shows a moon instead of a sun, by the knob going across the rectangle like in the normal UISwitch animation.

But as said, when I use RCSwitch, it ends up like this:

[image]

Which looks like garbage.

I also tried [TTSwitch](https://github.com/twotoasters/TTSwitch) to no avail, as it doesn't seem to work with images, only labels.

Can anyone offer me advice, either in how to implement it in one of those classes, or even in a completely different way that you think would be good?

Comment: Here's another alternative customizable switch: https://github.com/alexnauda/ERScrollSwitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using this custom extension from a friend of mine: [BMXSwitch](https://github.com/mbigatti/BMXSwitch). It's fully customizable and comes with a sample project to start working with it. Moreover, it also supports CocoaPods.

Comment: Oh wow, this I'll look into.

Comment: Did it solve your problems?

Comment: It may, I'll look into it later when I get the chance and if so I'll mark your answer accordingly. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Do you have any experience using it? I'm having some trouble integrating it (as far as making the images and sizing to create the switch).

Comment: Feel free to ask. Have you had problems using the sample project?

Comment: Yes, immensely, but I'm convinced I'm just doing something stupid. I'm having great difficulty swapping in the images in the example for my own and still have it work, mostly in regards to dimensions. Here's an example of what I've been trying (I've been trying to mimic as closely to the one that works as possible, then slowly transition to my design): http://cl.ly/3k1x1C3D0O0f I just can't get the dimensions down

Comment: You have to resize the provided images, if you want to use them. You correctly replaced the one you wish to use, now to change the default size just resize the other ones (eg. canvas, content and knob) so they have the desired height and width. I can see no difficulties here :)

Comment: The problem lied with the fact that the nib has an inflexibly sized object that represented the switch and was too big for my case. Thanks!

Comment: How can you change the text on the BMXSlider to something like "Male" and "Female"?  Is it built for images only?  thx.

Comment: I think it's just image-based. But you'd better contact the developer directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just build your own custom switch. Have  UIView of 35 pts height. Add to this the background image with the sun and moon at the extremities. Have another image embedded in the view for the knob.

Add a tap gesture recognizer which changes position of the knob image to the opposite end and also use the gesture callback to change a BOOL property which indicates the state of the switch. Setting the property moves the knob to the relevant position.

Once you get this working, add a swipe gesture recognizer that handles the swipes and moves the postion of the knob and changes the property.

Once this is done handle touchesMoved to change the x position of the knob. touchesEnded to check where the knob should end up  - if touches ended in first half of the switch, move knob to left, else move to right.

Listed the things to be done in order of complexity. You might find that just a tap gesture recognizer is enough for your app and you can live without implementing swipe or touch moved gestures.

Comment: Yeah, implementing a pan gesture recognizer to slide the switch was my biggest regret with going with this method, but I'll look into it. Thanks.